# How do I enable TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM and TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM cipher suites in Java?

Tags: java, tls1.2

I have a java application that needs to accept TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM and TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM ciphers. I'm using Spring's RestTemplate to manage incoming and outgoing HTTP requests, and I can't find anything on how to enable these cipher suites without some kind of BouncyCastle API.

Is there some kind of code string that will let my app accept these cipher suites? Or do I have to download something?

Comment: BouncyCastle is right tool for such purpose

Comment: @AntonAstafiev well, how do I enable the cipher suites with BouncyCastle API?

Comment: You'd want to say there are no such ciphers present? What's the problem of using them? I don't remember how exactly but extra ciphers can be plugged into BC in natural and obvious way.